# Vue SFC / vue-loader / webpack style include order

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

I have a vue/sfc/webpack/vue-loader application where I use bootstrap (via 'import') and component styles directly in the SFCs. Now vue-loader always includes bootstrap after the component styles so I can´t properly overwrite/cascade over bootstrap.

I tried scoping the component style and that somehow works, but bootstrap is still included after it. Working as intended?

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

component.vue

```
<style>

    input.form-control {
        border-width: 0px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        width: 6rem;
        display: inline;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: hi, are you using webpack extractTextPlugin plugin ?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah No, I don´t use it. I checked the github page but failed to see how this can help with the order issue. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real answer, but my solution was: replace webpack with https://parceljs.org/ Works (mostly) out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The import order matters. Import `bootstrap.css` first:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
```